# How can I add even-numbered rows to odd-numbered rows?

Tags: stata

My dataset is as follows.

```
1.  ZARA.  cotton.  35.  28.  27.  350.  0
2.          125.    3200.  1.  5.   32.  41
3.  Mango. nylon.   35.  27.  28.  320.  0
4.          125.    3050.  1.  5.   33.  40
```

and so on.

I want to move even numbered rows to odd numbered rows using Stata.

Just think using

```
loop {
      i = 1
      move  2i th row to 2i-1th row
      i = i + 1
      if i= 2k
      finish }
```

Comment: Spelling is Stata. It hasn't been STATA for more than 30 years.

Answer (score 0):

There is some ambiguity (meaning, lack of information) about whether your variables are string or numeric and about what is aligned with what, and you do not give variable names. Thus this falls short of a minimal, complete and verifiable example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve But this technique may help. I wouldn't explicitly loop over observations (not rows: Stata is not a spreadsheet).

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input str6 v1 str7 v2 str5 v3 str3(v4 v5) str4 v6 str2 v7
"ZARA."  "cotton." "35."   "28." "27." "350." "0" 
""       "125."    "3200." "1."  "5."  "32."  "41"
"Mango." "nylon."  "35."   "27." "28." "320." "0" 
""       "125."    "3050." "1."  "5."  "33."  "40"
end

quietly forval j = 8/13 {
    local i = `j' - 6
    gen v`j' = v`i'[_n+1] if mod(_n, 2) == 1
}

drop if mod(_n, 2) == 0

list

     +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
  1. |     v1 |      v2 |  v3 |  v4 |  v5 |   v6 | v7 |   v8 |    v9 | v10 | v11 |
     |  ZARA. | cotton. | 35. | 28. | 27. | 350. |  0 | 125. | 3200. |  1. |  5. |
     |---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
     |                 v12                 |                 v13                 |
     |                 32.                 |                  41                 |
     +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+

     +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
  2. |     v1 |      v2 |  v3 |  v4 |  v5 |   v6 | v7 |   v8 |    v9 | v10 | v11 |
     | Mango. |  nylon. | 35. | 27. | 28. | 320. |  0 | 125. | 3050. |  1. |  5. |
     |---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
     |                 v12                 |                 v13                 |
     |                 33.                 |                  40                 |
     +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Here

`_n` is the observation number running 1 up.

`mod(_n, 2)` is the remainder on dividing observation number by 2 and is thus 1 for odd numbers and 0 for even numbers.

You may want to `destring` whatever is string but should be numeric.

EDIT Here's another way to do it, but it hinges on all variables being string.

```
clear
input str6 v1 str7 v2 str5 v3 str3(v4 v5) str4 v6 str2 v7
"ZARA."  "cotton." "35."   "28." "27." "350." "0" 
""       "125."    "3200." "1."  "5."  "32."  "41"
"Mango." "nylon."  "35."   "27." "28." "320." "0" 
""       "125."    "3050." "1."  "5."  "33."  "40"
end

gen long id = _n 
gen odd = mod(_n, 2) 
reshape long v, i(id) j(varno) 
replace id = ceil(id/2) 
replace varno = varno + 6 if !odd 
drop if missing(v) 
drop odd
reshape wide v, i(id) j(varno)
```